# Prepend SCroll Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have created an infinite scroll

My Html Code

```
<div id="Container">
 // search results goes here
</div>
```

To Add data at end

```
 $(oneTuple).appendTo("#Container"); //oneTuple is information of one tuple of search results page
```

To Prepend

```
$(oneTuple).appendTo("#Container");
```

Issue:
When i add data using appendTo, my position of cursor changes.
Can i make sure my cursor wont change even if i add data

Comment: So if oneTuple is visible on screen and you add another to the list, then you don't want the list to scroll? Is it actually the cursor moving or is the page moving under the cursor so to speak?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to calculate the current scroll position ScrollTop(), then append/prepend the data, calculate the difference in current vs previous scroll position, then use the ScrollTo() method to scroll to end again.